# ajax post success function not being fired?

Tags: jquery, node.js

Hi I am making an ajax post to '/messages/new' where it is console.logging the data that is posted to it, and then on the client it is console.logging "posted" if it is successfully posted. However it is not console.logging posted

Here is my form handling on the client:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('contactmeform')[0].addEventListener('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = {
        name: e.target.name.value,
        phone_or_email: e.target.phone_or_email.value,
        message: e.target.message.value
    }


    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/message/new",
      data: data,
      success: function(){
        console.log('postedd')
      }
    });
})
```

EDIT: console.log is working on the server, but the success callback function is not being fired on the client, so I am not seeing "posted" in my browsers console.
How can I get the success function to fire?

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: console not workin in ajax success or at the route ?

Comment: Ajax success callback isn't working so I am not seeing "posted" in my browsers console. I edited my question for clarification @SKJajoriya

Comment: Try my updated answer

Comment: What does the network tab of the browser developer tools show for the request. And you should allways register the fail callback so that you can handle/debug the error case.

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/message/new',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    return true;
})
```

Then at ajax success

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/message/new",
      data: data,
      success: function(response){
        if(response) {
        console.log('postedd')
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, on the server I added:

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    res.write(JSON.stringify({ status: "OK" }));
    res.end();
```

because in my network tab in dev tools it said that the request was still pending and this fixed it. My full post handling on the server now looks like:

```
app.post('/message/new',function(req,res){
console.log(req.body.name);
console.log(req.body.phone_or_email);
console.log(req.body.message);
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
res.write(JSON.stringify({ status: "OK" }));
res.end();
```

})